# Get the QPixmap from a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QLabel` called `Picture` which `Pixmap` has been set to a `QImage`.
I now want to modify the image in another function.
Is it possible to get the `Pixmap`from the `Picture`?

I tried the following, which results in an unhandled exception:

```
QPixmap const *pm = ui.Picture->pixmap();  
QImage image(pm->toImage());
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you shall check the return value of the `pixmap()` function.

```
const QPixmap* pixmap = ui.Picture->pixmap();
if ( pixmap )
{
    QImage image( pixmap->toImage() );
}
```

Maybe you just called the function when the image was not set and that caused the exception.