# Saving an image from a label to disc

Tags: c++, qt

I've just spent 3 hours with the relevant documentation, but I don't understand it (I'm a complete noobie). I have a jpg image in a label (the label is named 'screen') - and I simply want to save it to disc giving it a generated filename, which I've got. I've looked at Qimage, and QPixmap, but it's all beyond me. How can I get the image which is being displayed on the label, and save it to disc? It must be very easy, but I can not do it. The problem seems to be getting the image from the label into a QPixmap or a QImage so that I can save it. Please help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304995/get-the-qpixmap-from-a-qlabel

Comment: @Hooder: If Arnav's suggestion solves your problem we'll just mark this question as duplicate. Is it a solution?

Comment: Seriously...Opening the documentation for `QLabel`, pressing `Ctrl+F` to activate search on that page, typing in `pixmap` and the very first result is http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy. Example:

```
const QPixmap* pix = myLabel->pixmap();
if(pix)
    pix->save("save/path/img.jpg");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it IS easy when you know how :)